# React Native Web, FlatList expands page

Tags: reactjs, react-native, scrollview, react-native-web, flatlist

I have some app, that looks like this

[image]

I need FlattList to scroll independently, but instead of that it's expand the page and scrolls with everything else.

I've tried to play with layout, changing 'flex' and 'justify' params, but it didn't give me any results.

The only thing that forced FlatList to scroll by itself was changing the height of parent View by hand, that obviously not a solution.

[image]

```
import React from 'react'; import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput , FlatList, Image} from 'react-native';


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    head: {
        height: 64,
        alignSelf: 'stretch',
        alignItems: 'center',
        flexDirection: 'row',

        backgroundColor: "#FFF",
        shadowColor: "#000",
    },

    search: {
        height: 48,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
        borderRadius: 16,

        marginBottom: 8,
        backgroundColor: "#FFF",
    },

    card: {
        height: 240,
        margin: 8,
        backgroundColor: "#FFF",
        borderRadius: 16,
    },

    filtersCard: {
        width: 280,
        height: 500,
        marginLeft: 16,
        paddingBottom: 34,
        alignItems: 'center',

        backgroundColor: "#FFF",
        borderRadius: 16,
    },

    filtersCardText: {
        alignSelf: 'start',
        fontSize: 24,
        marginBottom: 8,
        marginTop: 16,
        marginLeft: 24,
    } });

const App = () => {   return (
      <View style = {{
          flex: 1,
          backgroundColor: '#cCcFd1',
          alignItems: 'center',
      }}>
          <View style = {styles.head}>
              <Text style = {{fontSize: 48, fontWeight:900, paddingLeft: 16, selectable: false}}>HEAD (shouldn't move)</Text>
          </View>

          <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: "flex-start", marginTop: 16}}>
              <View style={{width: 872}}>
                  <View style={styles.search}><Text>  Search (shouldn't move)</Text></View>

                  <View style={{height: 400}}>
                      <FlatList
                          data={[ 1, 2, 3, 5, 8]} //just for demo
                          renderItem={({item}) => <View style={styles.card}/>}
                      />
                  </View>

              </View>

              <View style={styles.filtersCard}><Text> Filters (shouldn't move)</Text></View>
          </View>
      </View>

  ); }

export default App;
```

Comment: Put your <FlatList> within <ScrollView>: `<ScrollView> <View> <FlatList/> </View> </ScrollView>`

Comment: Nope. It didn't help(

Comment: Do you still need help with this question?

Comment: I have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TextInput,
  FlatList,
  Image,
  SafeAreaView,
} from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.wrapper}>
      <View style={styles.head}>
        <Text>Head (shouldn't move)</Text>
      </View>
      <View
        style={styles.body}>
        <View style={styles.col1}>
          <View style={styles.search}>
            <Text> Search (shouldn't move)</Text>
          </View>

          <View style={{ height: 400, flex: 1 }}>
            <FlatList
              data={[1, 2, 3, 5, 8]} //just for demo
              renderItem={({ item }) => <View style={styles.card} />}
            />
          </View>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.col2}>
          <Text> Filters (shouldn't move)</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default App;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  wrapper: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#cCcFd1',
  },

  head: {
    backgroundColor: '#FFF',
  },

  body: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'flex-start',
    marginTop: 16,
    flex: 1,
  },

  search: {
    marginBottom: 8,
    backgroundColor: '#FFF',
  },

  card: {
    height: 240,
    backgroundColor: '#FFF',
    marginVertical: 8,
  },

  col1: {
    width: '60%',
  },

  col2: {
    height: 500,
    width: '40%',
    marginLeft: 16,
    backgroundColor: '#FFF',
  },
});
```

https://snack.expo.io/JR8D0GNd_

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you changed and why it solved it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using React Navigation, try to put "flex: 1" in cardStyle attribute of your stack screenOptions.

```
<Stack.Navigator
    ...
  screenOptions={{
    cardStyle: {
      width: "100%",
      flex: 1,
    },
  }}
>
  ...
</Stack.Navigator>;
```

Then make sure that every screen size wrappers from Your navigation screen to the flatList are in "flex: 1"